# json request with data variables - how do I read the variable in the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, variables

Loading in a bunch of json files from an array called bunchOfData. The .url is the url for each json file.

How do I read my variable "myI" in the *processData* function?

```
for(var i = 0; i < bunchOfData.length; i++){
        $.getJSON(bunchOfData[i].url, {"myI":i}, function(ds){}).success(processData);

        function processData(ds){
            console.log(ds.myI); //undefined
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific. Post your json object.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(arguments)` ?

Comment: Do you want to get the `myI` value you *sent* inside `processData`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yes. I want it inside processData. The processData function only fires if the data gets fired if the json is loaded successfully.

Comment: @Shanimal yes, I see 2 objects and a "success." But no myI.

Comment: @Dynamicus my json objects are very long. Won't help to post here. I have no trouble getting them to load, just can't seem to "find" my variable I'm passing.

Comment: @Shaz ds is the server response, so unless its being echoed you won't see it there. I have a sample below showing how to capture the value in a closure

Answer (score 1):

```
function successHandler(i){
    console.log('i is instantiated/stored in the closure scope:',i);
    return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
        // here, the server response and a reference to 'i'
        console.log('i from the closure scope:',i, 'other values',data,textStatus,jqXHR);
    }            
}

var i = 0; i < bunchOfData.length; i++){
    $.getJSON(bunchOfData[i].url, {"myI":i}, function(ds){}).success(successHandler(i));

}
```

Comment: Okay, so that allows me to get the correct "i" but doesn't send my ds (dataset). If I do handler(ds, i), it doesn't know what ds is. Anyway for me to pass the i and the ds in that handler function?

Comment: Change `return function(){` to `return function(ds){`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat ? "return function" isn't written anywhere. It's just function(ds)

Comment: @SShazboticus: Inside `function handler(i){`.

Comment: You'll have to write it out. I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: oh, I think I get what you're saying... one sec

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. ds object data isn't returned in the function. I just get the code of the function itself

Comment: @SShazboticus ds is the server response, so unless its being echoed by your server you won't see it there...

Comment: also if you add i as a parameter to your handler you'll overwrite the closure instance of i where i from the loop is stored.

Comment: @Shanimal so what do you suggest?

Comment: What CGI is serving your JSON?

Comment: I'm just running it off my local webserver (localhost). Trying to keep things simple.

Comment: so you're serving a static json files?

Comment: Yes. In the future, it'll be generated by a database. But like I said, starting simple.

Comment: Maybe start here. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ The only way 'i' or the data sent in the request would be available in that handler/callback is if the server returns it or you wrap it in a closure. It could be available in the jqxhr-object but I'd have to explore that further: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR The only thing in ds is what the server returns (which in this case is static JSON?)

Comment: btw the parameters for the success handler are `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` these are described in the manual

Comment: I understand. Basically the server won't send me back "myI" and I need a way of getting the correct value of myI at the same time as the server returns ds. @jqXHR comment, yeah, I've been using ds, g, z. I often just add letters to see if a function will return me more information.

Comment: Only solution I know of is to take this out of a for loop and make it a "loading loop" where each time a json file is loaded, it increments i.

Comment: The handler as shown stores a unique instance of i that corresponds to the i used when it was called. So when it return it will have the appropriate value

Comment: check out the new successHandler function. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. I wrote a solution that works but it's really ugly. I was just hoping what I had initially was just some error in syntax or something.

Comment: ha, ok. I added comments to further explain. Run that against your list of urls in the js console.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access varibles outside of scope, the response will only be valid

```
function(ds){
    // Here
}
```

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bunchOfData.length; i++){
    $.getJSON(bunchOfData[i].url, {"myI":i}, function(ds){
        console.log(ds);
    });
}
```

Also once the request is finished and was successfull contents of `success` will run, note that what you are trying to achive can be dont with a single request (you can unify the files and serv them in a single one), so you get the data and then iterate.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. One of the first things I tried. =/

Comment: What does the console say XMLHttpRequests? whats the response for the request?

Comment: console says object for each one and I can view the contents. (Chrome)

Comment: if you can view the contents this means the `console.log(ds);` outputs the object and `ds` contains your data you just need to use the correct keys...